# esp8266 programme memory corruption

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266

I programmed arduino sketch direct to ESP8266, then my code works fine. When I remove USB to power off the board, and then power it up again and inserting USB, my code is not working.

It seems like Esp8266 failing to read program memory or is there anything I am missing when I am powering up the board?

I am not sure, my board have issue or I am missing something.

Any one have faced this kind of issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Those who will face this problem in future, actually my program memory was fine. I forgot remove Gnd pin from GPIO 0 after I programmed the esp8266.